# Android Count The Letter

Tags: java, android, string, count, letter

I am trying to count how many times the letter A will be output in my program. here is what I have so far...

```
count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
               int letter1 = 0;
               int letter2 = 0;
               String enter1 = str1.getText().toString();
               String enter2 = str2.getText().toString();

               for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
                   if (enter1.charAt(i) == "a") {
                       letter1++;
               }
               display2.setText(enter1);
           }
       }
   });
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error: incomparable types: char and String
                   if (enter1.charAt(i) == "a") {
```

Comment: `if (enter1.charAt(i) == 'a') `, you use single quotes for single characters, e.g. 'a', 'b', 'c'...etc

Comment: you might also want to compare for 'A', so would be `if (enter1.charAt(i) == 'a' || enter1.charAt(i) == 'A')`

Comment: Do I have to do something special with the String enter1 to make it accept Char and not just String?

Comment: A string is basically a cominbation of characters right. A `char` type at most contains only a single character. So your best bet is to just scan through the characters of enter1 for what you need to do. So you can't convert all String to char but you could probably convert it to `char` array or sequence`

Comment: ````                 for(int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j ++){
                     if(enter2.charAt(j) == 'a' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'e' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'i' || enter2.charAt(j) == 'o' ||
                             enter2.charAt(j) == 'u')
                     {
                         letter2++;